# how do i extract first string from specific text

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

i need to extract string from a text  as following example

```
Hi i have no name <z>empty</z>
```

i wanted to extract only text before `<z>`  into array or string which is `hi i have no name`
i tried this function

```
procedure Split (const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings);
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.StrictDelimiter := true;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;
```

but its only can split chars like  `;,:` etc.. i wanted to start split with this specific  string `<z>`

Comment: If `<z>` is the sep, then `empty</z>` is the second string, right. Or do you need an XML parser.

Comment: i wanted to read string before `<z>` kinda like `string := Copy(Hi i have no name <z>empty</z>, 1, Pos('<z>', Hi i have no name <z>empty</z>)-1);`

Comment: `s := Copy(s,1,Pos('<z>',s)-1);` you mean?

Comment: Hope you're not going to parse HTML that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I read what you have written, you have a string and you want to ignore all text after the first occurrence of `<z>`. Use `Pos` and `Copy` for instance:

```
P := Pos('<z>', input);
if P = 0 then 
  output := input
else 
  output := Copy(input, 1, P-1);
```

Although something tells me that you really want an XML parser.

Comment: thats exactly what i searched for thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

Just an example using the string helper routines:

```
function CutString(const input,pattern: String): String;
var
  p: Integer;
begin
  p := input.IndexOf(pattern);
  if (p >= 0) then
    Result := input.Substring(0,p)
  else
    Result := input;
end;

var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Hi i have no name<z>empty</z>';
  s := CutString(s,'<z>');
  WriteLn(s);  // Outputs: 'Hi i have no name'
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for the *one-liner-fan*, the *crack-nuts-with-sledgehammer-lover*, the *regex-enthusiast*, the *waste-performance-ignorant* and the *xml-parser-grump*:

```
TRegEx.Replace('Hi i have no name <z>empty</z>', '((^.*)(?=<z>)|(^.*)(?!<z>)).*', '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter will be there for sure, you can do:

```
Result:= Copy(S, 1, Pos(Delimiter, S) - 1);
```

Otherwise user Davids answer or this (shorter but bad performance):

```
Result:= Copy(S, 1, Pos(Delimiter, S + Delimiter) - 1);
```